# Searching text for a long list of substrings

Tags: python, string, performance, substring

Problem: Given a set of ~250000 integer user IDs, and about a terabyte of JSON-formatted one-per-line records, load the records in which the user ID matches to a database.

Only about 1% of all the records will match the 250000 user IDs. Rather than JSON decode each record, which takes a long time, I am trying to use string matching to determine if the user ID is in the raw JSON; if it matches, then the JSON is decoded and the record checked and then inserted.

The problem is that matching one string of raw JSON against a set containing ~250k string entries is slow.

Here's the code so far:

```
// get the list of integer user IDs
cur.execute('select distinct user_id from users')

// load them as text into a set
users = set([])
for result in cur.fetchall():
    users.add(str(result[0]))

// start working on f, the one-json-record-per-line text file
for line in f:
    scanned += 1
    if any(user in line for user in users):
        print "got one!"
        // decode json
        // check for correct decoded user ID match
        // do insert
```

I am approaching this the right way? What's a faster method of matching these strings? At present, when looking for so many user IDs, this manages ~2 entries a second on a 3ghz machine (not so good). When the list of user IDs is very short, it manages ~200000 entries/second.

Comment: It seems like a real database might be a better solution for something like this.  Unfortunately, I don't use databases so I can't recommend anything (although I'm guessing someone else will)

Comment: Oof, that `any` inside a `for` loop is VERY expensive. Exponential growth of your actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) appears to be built for this purpose. There's even a handy Python module for it (easy_install ahocorasick).

```
import ahocorasick

# build a match structure
print 'init empty tree'
tree = ahocorasick.KeywordTree()

cur.execute('select distinct user_id from users')

print 'add usernames to tree'
for result in cur.fetchall():
   tree.add(str(result[0]))

print 'build fsa'
tree.make()

for line in f:
     scanned += 1
     if tree.search(line) != None:
         print "got one!"
```

This reaches closer to ~450 entries per second.

Comment: If you are looking for a **integer** values which you will read from the input line I suspect that very simple array will be much faster. I.e. instead of `tree.add(str(result[0]))` do `arrayValues[result[0]] = result[0];` and then instead of `if tree.search(line) != None:` do `if arrayValues[line] != null`

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the matching algorithm:

```
for digit_sequence in re.findall('[0-9]+', line):
    if digit_sequence in users:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am C++ freelancer, and my clients usually are startups which have some slow python/java/.net/etc code and they want it run faster. I usually can make it x100 times faster.  Just recently I had similar to question task: to implement search of 5 million substrings in terabytes of text data.

I've tested several algorithms.  For Aho–Corasick, I've used open source http://sourceforge.net/projects/multifast/. It was not fastest algorithm. Fastest was my algorithm which I've concocted from mixture of hash table and with some ideas taken from Rabin–Karp search algo.  This simple algorithm was x5 times faster and used x5 times less memory than AC. Average substring length was 32 bytes.  So, AC might be not the fastest algo for this.